# Ignore case in golang reflection FieldByName

Tags: go, reflection, reflect

I am trying read from a struct using reflection in golang which I was able to do successfully but I am wondering what can I do to ignore case of a field name.

I have the below code

```
type App struct{
    AppID        string
    Owner        string
    DisplayName  string
}

func Extract(app *App){
appData := reflect.ValueOf(app)
appid := reflect.Indirect(appData).FieldByName("appid")
fmt.Println(appid.String())
owner:=reflect.Indirect(appData).FieldByName("owner")
fmt.Println(owner.String())
}
```

The above function returns `<invalid-value>` for both and its because of the lower case of the field name

**Is there a way I could ignore the case?**

Comment: I would assume not, since you can have different fields in a struct with the same name with different capitalization.

Comment: Golang also does not support property aliasing, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Value.FieldByNameFunc](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.FieldByNameFunc) and [strings.ToLower](https://godoc.org/strings#ToLower) to ignore case when finding a field:

```
func caseInsenstiveFieldByName(v reflect.Value, name string) reflect.Value {
    name = strings.ToLower(name)
    return v.FieldByNameFunc(func(n string) bool { return strings.ToLower(n) == name })
}
```

Use it like this:

```
func Extract(app *App) {
    appData := reflect.ValueOf(app)
    appid := caseInsenstiveFieldByName(reflect.Indirect(appData), "appid")
    fmt.Println(appid.String())
    owner := caseInsenstiveFieldByName(reflect.Indirect(appData), "owner")
    fmt.Println(owner.String())
}
```

[Run it on the Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5oUOambPjFZ).

Comment: An addition, now you can use `strings.EqualFold` function.